# X-bar Theory WH and DP movements

Tags: x-bar-theory

this year I opted to study English syntax as a non native speaker and we arrived to the movements on the X-bar theory. We are studying DP and WH movements on sentences, and while I'm able to understand the examples given on the text book(Syntax a generative introduction) but then I'm stuck on the exercises.

We have been told that exam exercises will be harder than this ones, but I'm not able to even do those two.

What do you think John has bought at the supermarket?

He did not know which offer was rejected by the committee.

If someone could give me an overview of how those two sentences are drawn, I think I could understand where I'm lost.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Seriously, X-bar trees don't help you understand English or its grammar; they only help you pass tests in some syntax classes. After that, the information is pretty useless, as shown by the fact that you're not being helped by learning it.

Comment: I know, but the x-bar is half of the exam, I may be able to do the other half perfect, but I preffer not risking it. I know that after the exam, all the x-bar theory is going to the recycle bin.

Answer (score 0):

How it cannot be a Head-to-Head movement because we are moving an entire phrase, there are several elements that have been moved. Firstly, the present tense on the higher T requires do-support and [+Q] triggers T→C movement. Secondly, from a V position [think] has been moved to the specifier position of CP [+WH]. The DP [John] has been moved from the specifier of the embedded VP to the specifier of the embedded TP. The DP [you] does the same in the higher clause. Finally, we have wh-movement, after moving first to the specifier of the embedded CP and then, on to the higher CP to check that C's [+WQ] feature.

Comment: This series of video will help you out as well. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OBGA9DZT6Ns&list=PLDDGPdw7e6AgiXk85UJB8YPrerW2TdlkF  Thetrevtutor y really useful, above all with the neg-clauses like the second one "he did not..."

Comment: Yes, yesterday after I post the question I started seeing his videos, they were really helpful. As for the response, It is more or less what I ended up (kinda long trees as they make us specify every aspect of the phrase). Thanks ;).